# How does a corona wire charge a printer drum?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

I understand how a laser printer works and some of the principles of static electricity, such as how objects gain a charge by electron transfer but don't understand how a high voltage corona wire can give the printer drum a net charge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small-diameter high voltage corona wire is surrounded by an extremely high voltage *field gradient* immediately next to the surface of the wire. for a small enough wire diameter and a high enough (negative) voltage, it becomes possible to pluck electrons out of the wire surface and propel them away from the wire, creating a *space charge* surrounding the wire consisting of air molecules which have picked up one of these free electrons.

If we place the toner drum surface close by, and give it a positive charge, then it attracts the negatively-charged ions which then impinge upon its surface and build up there as a net surface charge.

Comment: Does this give the drum a final negative charge?

Comment: I do not know if the net residual charge on the drum is - or +. But it is the opposite of the charge given to the toner dust.